# Grouping by multiple attributes and eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple model on Rails 4.0.0:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :instances
end

class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
    # attribute: completion_result
end
```

I want to fetch the `count` of instances grouped by `Template` and `completion_result`. My query looks like this:

```
    Instance.joins(:template)
            .where('templates.enabled = ?', true)
            .group(:template_id, :completion_result)
            .count
```

This works great, and I get a result such as:

```
{[7, "ok"]=>2, [10, "ok"]=>1, [8, nil]=>2,
 [8, "cancel"]=>2, [9, "ok"]=>1, [8, "ok"]=>5}
```

In other query, where I'm grouping by a single attribute, I can specify `group(:template)` instead of `group(:template_id)` and that will make the key of the `Hash` be an `ActiveRecord` instance instead, thus helping me get rid of an n + 1 query scenario.

In this case, since I'm grouping by multiple keys, if I change my `group` to `group(:template, :completion_result)` Rails will generate an invalid query (it will try to select `template` instead of `template_id`, which doesn't exist).

Is this a bug a Rails or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this

```
Template.all.select('templates.*, COUNT(1) as count').select(:completion_result).joins(:instances).where(enable: true).group(:id).group(:completion_result).map{|x| {[x,x.completion_result] => x.count }}
```